# What breed of dog was Tobiah's dog?

Tags: tobit

Does anyone have any idea what breed of dog Tobiah's dog might have been?

Referenced in [Tobit 6](http://www.usccb.org/bible/tobit/6) and [Tobit 11](http://www.usccb.org/bible/tobit/11)

Answer (score 7):

It was likely a [Canaan dog](http://cdca.org/history.html), or rather its ancestor the desert pariah dog, which appears to be the only breed indigenous to that area.